# C++ will thread created in class share the same class variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a class like this

```
class ThreadPool
{
public:
    ThreadPool();
    ThreadPool(int total_thread);
    ~ThreadPool();
    void active_pool(void);
    void* thread_start_routine(void* run_data);

private:
    int total_thread_;
    queue<TASK*> task_queue;
    sem_t* task_queue_mutex_;//Same function as mutex semaphore in P-C problem.
    sem_t* task_queue_full_;//Same function as full semaphore in P-C problem.
};
```

And I will create multiple thread within the active_pool function and each thread entry-function is thread_start_routine.

**My question is that if each have to push/pop with queue task_queue, will all threads see the same queue or each queue they see is just a local copy through thread creation**

**Thank you~**

Answer (score 2):

All threads will see the same queue. That's the beauty of concurrent programming. (You can use `thread_local` storage duration if you want a different instance per thread - this is a new addition to C++ since C++11.)

Normally, you need to make sure the relevant members are used in a thread-safe manner. Atomic types (`std::atomic` from C++11) and mutual exclusion units (`std::mutex` from C++11) are used for that.

References:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

Comment: @HaohaoChang Threads all share the address space of the same process. If you don' want a shared address space then you don't want threads but instead separate processes that each have their own address space.